# Iterate through chunks of data and iterate again for each element in that chunk

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, iteration, chunks

So here is my problem (Python language):

I have a set of data of x number of rows and y number of columns. In addition, the data is split in n number of chunks, each one having s number of rows.

I am trying to find a way to iterate through each n chunk of s number of rows, and then within each nth chunk of rows, have another iteration that goes through each s rows to multiply a certain  y column with a value (let's say 10**nth chunk index) and then with another column.

So for example, let's say my data looks like:

```
    Velocity Distance Energy Drag

    10E2      20        30      2
    10E3      40        10      1
    10E4      50        50      6
    10E3      20        20      5
    10E7      110       70      9
    
    10E2      10        30      2
    10E3      50        10      9
    10E4      80        50      6
    10E3      15        20      8
    10E7      120       70      9
    
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to:

1. Iterate through each chunk of 5x4.
2. Within each chunk, I want to iterate again in the s rows;
3. Take the energy and multiply it by a factor for 10E2*n. For example: For first chunk (index  0): Energy*10E2*0.
4. Then take the energy elements and multiply it by their distance. For example: 30*10E2*0*10E2.
5. Then repeat that for all of the elements in that chunk and then obtain the average and store it in an array.
6. Iterate through the next chunk with index n and so on.

Any help would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what calculations you want to do in each row. You say multiply by the number of the chunk but then you indicate some sort of exponentiation. What you're asking for can definitely be done with a few lines of code, if you simply provide an example of what the calculations for that first chunk would result in.